# Is it ok to make a new invoice if an old one is lost?

Tags: legal, taxes, invoices, usa

If I lost an old invoice or had mistakenly put wrong information in that invoice (like a missing field or wrong address), is it ok to generate a new one with the same amount, send it to the client and use it for tax and legal records?

Invoices have been given. I have already been paid. Invoices are all emails so digital. No other documents exist.

Comment: Duplicating an invoice can be an accounting headache depending on how your systems are integrated? How is an invoice, "lost", if it's electronic getting, "lost", isn't an option and if it's not electronic it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reissuing an invoice should be fine as long as it is clear why the invoice has been reissued. This could be done by annotating the new invoice appropriately such as, "Invoice [number] reissued with amended address" or similar. For obvious reasons it is especially important to be clear about whether the invoice amount has changed or not and whether it needs to be reprocessed or not. It should also be clear if this is an adjustment to an existing invoice or if this replaces an old invoice and ideally whether payment has already been received or not.

Once it is received, and assuming the explanation is clear, it can then be appropriately processed including any financial adjustment if needed.

Similarly at your end, you need to make sure you are not duplicating the same transaction by processing the original and the replacement invoice.